# 401 Access Denied for Emotion API but not for Face API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

when I get a 401 error when testing the microsoft cognitive Emotion API, but not the Face API - I'm using the same subscription key and region for both. Why is that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emotion API has been deprecated and is now part of the Face API.  Details can be found on the home page of the `[Emotion API documentation][1]`.  So, what you are experiencing with the key working in Face but not Emotion is expected.